# Uploadify and JSP/Java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I just started working with Uploadify with our Java/JSP Applications and for that I use a servlet instead of the upload.php to do the upload to the server.

I was wondering if there is any servlet example ?? or anyone has additional info for those of us that use JSP instead of PHP?

I follow the example but it doesn't seem to do anything. i changed the script attribute to a JSP file and it doesn't get called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#fileUpload1").fileUpload({
         'uploader': 'mypath/uploader.swf',
         'cancelImg': 'mypath/cancel.png',
         'script': 'mypath/upload.php', // a jsp file???
         'folder': 'files',
         'multi' : false
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: JSP is intented for presentation only, not to do some business logic. Let the URL point to a servlet and follow Bozho's advice about a robust API to process file uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better be using [commons file-upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html). In the link provided there are details on how exactly to us it in a servlet of yours.